# Get current MembershipProvider name

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 membership api in web form application.

I want to get the name on the current membershipProvider during runtime (either "UmbracoMembershipProvider" or "UsersMembershipProvider").

Can someone help?

Thanks

Indra

this is the web.config section

```
<!-- Membership Provider -->
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<!-- added by NH to support membership providers in access layer -->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

The reason(if it is needed): to detect if a user control is deployed/integrated in live umbraco deployment vs visual studio independent debugging session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using -> Membership.Provider.Name